# Creating a grow/shrink timer breaks when multiple div elements are used

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, setinterval

I've been playing with JavaScript and jQuery lately, and I decided that I wanted to make divs grow when the mouse enters the region of a div, and for it to shrink when it leaves. It works fine when I only have one div, or only one running at a time, but if I were to leave the region of one, and enter another before the other one finishes shrinking, it breaks.

Here's the JS & jQuery code I'm using:

```
var timers = [];
var maxSize = 150;
var minSize = 100;
var step = 1;

function grow(element) {
    var size = element.width();
    if (size < maxSize) {
        var newSize = size + step;
        if (newSize > maxSize) newSize = maxSize;
        element.css('width', newSize);
        element.css('height', newSize);
    } else {
        window.clearInterval(timers[element]);
    }
}

function shrink(element) {
    var size = element.width();
    if (size > minSize) {
        var newSize = size - step;
        if (newSize < minSize) newSize = minSize;
        element.css('width', newSize);
        element.css('height', newSize);
    } else {
        window.clearInterval(timers[element]);
    }
}

function inArray(element, array) {
    if ($.inArray(element, array) > 1) return true;
    return false;
}

$("div").mouseover(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    if (inArray(element, timers)) window.clearInterval(timers[element]);
    else timers.push(element);

    timers[element] = window.setInterval(function() {
        grow(element);
    }, 0);
});

$("div").mouseleave(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    window.clearInterval(timers[element]);
    timers[element] = window.setInterval(function() {
        shrink(element);
    }, 0);
});
```

Since I've put the elements in an array, they shouldn't have a problem with multiple divs resizing at once, and I'm not sure what I've done wrong. ([And here's a JSFiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/gsm7228w/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are just playing around javascript. But just for the record, you can acheive that with a couple lines of css and no javascript:

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    transition: .5s;
}
div:hover {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: I didn't know about that! I was just playing with javascript/jquery, and this was plenty more simple. :)